# Image max width responsive and auto

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```
<style>
    .img-body {
        height: 350px;
        width: auto;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="img-body">
    <img src="banner1629290852.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

I have two images.
One is of 515px and second one is 264px.

My rendering screen size is 375px.

I want if actual size of image is greater than rendering screen size then in this case my image should rendered equal to rendering screen size i.e 515px image should rendered equal to 375px.

and if actual size of image is less than rendering screen size then in this case my image should take actual size while rendering. It should not spread according to rendered size. i.e image of size 264px should display in 264 px not spread to 375px.

Comment: be more spcific?

Comment: if image actual size is greater than rendered width then image should take same width as rendered width.  and if image actual size is less than rednered width then the image should take its actual size and doesnot spread according to rendered size.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .img-body {
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="img-body">
    <img src="banner1629290852.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding object-fit: scale-down; to your img class, should look like this:

```
<style>
.img-body {
    height: 350px;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: scale-down;
}
</style>

<div class="img-body">
    <img src="banner1629290852.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to set `max-width` to 100% and `width` to auto.

```
<style>
.img-body {
    height: 350px;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
```